# Why am I not able to create android xml file?

Tags: android, xml, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, galaxy-tab

I am creating a new project, target of this project is "GALAXY tab addon". I am creating a new xml file in layout folder an I am getting following screen which was not the case when I was developing for 2.2 or so. Where do I go next, it says the options are "optional" so I skipped them and clicked finish- No Response, I also tried selecting some options and still the file is not creating. What am i missing here?

[image]

IDE used is Eclipse.

Comment: Explore resource, then you can see Folder: Layout.  Right click on it > New > Other > Android > Android XML File > "Give File Name" > [Select Layout if you want] > FINISH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to go till this window.you can finish creating xml file before this window like the below image.

[image]

Just click on finish button here and your xml file will be created.